# REPLACE function not available in AS/400 DB2

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to replace or remove the “ - “ character from read data in DB2/400 IBM System i mid-frame. Its very common in MS-SQL to make replacement using REPLACE function but here in DB2/400 V5R2 it seems that this function is not available. 
Could anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: Could you post your code please? REPLACE should be available in DB2.

Comment: it seems in DB2 is available but in DB2/400 not available

Comment: Per the v5r2 reference as a reply in another *comment* from the OP, might I suggest [as should always be done] that the Version Release Modification level [V5R2M0; V#R# is typical when M=0, for whatever reason] be included in the Opening Post\text.  If not edited to do so, at least that VRM now appears here in the comment to the OP rather than buried in one of the answer(s).  By mention of AS/400 and DB2/400 versus IBM i on Power and DB2 for i a reader easily might infer an older release, but their presumption of a release as old as v5r2 is a tenuous expectation of the readers to intuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightly tested on v5r3, the following is a *somewhat functional* User Defined Function (UDF) version of a [for lack of a DB2/400 SQL-supplied] REPLACE scalar on v5r2; the term "somewhat" meaning, that the defaulted mixed vs SBCS and CCSID for typing along with the specified lengths limiting the varying character string inputs and return value, though those can be adjusted by the invoker of the CREATE FUNCTION according to the needs of whomever will invoke the previously created REPLACEX scalar UDF:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION REPLACEX /* private version of REPLACE() */
   ( SRC_STR VARCHAR(5000) /* source string; for mixed data or ccsid 1208? */
   , FND_STR VARCHAR( 100) /* search string */                               
   , RPL_STR VARCHAR( 100) /* replace-with string */                         
   ) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) /* return string; for mixed data or ccsid 1208? */
   LANGUAGE SQL                                                              
   SPECIFIC REPLACEX                                                         
   RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT                                                
   NO EXTERNAL ACTION                                                        
   ALLOW PARALLEL                                                            
   SET OPTION SRTSEQ=*HEX                                                    
            , DECMPT=*PERIOD                                                 
            , DBGVIEW=*SOURCE                                                
  BEGIN                                                                      
   declare strpos int default 1 ;  /* start position for locate */           
   declare nxtpos int default 0 ;  /* next "found" position     */           
   declare fndlen int default 0 ;  /* length of fnd_str         */           
   declare rtnstr varchar(8000) default '' ; /* result-string   */           
   set nxtpos = locate( fnd_str, src_str, strpos ) ;                         
   set fndlen = length( fnd_str ) ;                                          
   while ( nxtpos > 0 ) do                                                   
    set rtnstr = rtnstr                                                      
          concat substr( src_str, strpos, ( nxtpos - strpos ) )              
          concat rpl_str                                                     
    ;                                                             
    set strpos = nxtpos + fndlen ;                                
    set nxtpos = locate( fnd_str, src_str , strpos ) ;            
    if ( nxtpos > 0 ) then /* adjust per *start* spec on LOCATE */
     set nxtpos = nxtpos + strpos - 1 ;                           
    end if ;                                                      
   end while ;                                                    
   set rtnstr = rtnstr                                            
         concat substr( src_str, strpos )                         
   ;                                                              
   return                                                         
      rtnstr                                                      
   ;                                                              
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

You must actually be using DB2/400...

Currently supported version of DB2 for i (6.1, 7.1 & 7.2) have a REPLACE() function.

My DB2 for i5/OS v5r4 reference also shows REPLACE().

It appears that REPLACE() was added to DB2 for iSeries v5r3; which was release in June 2004.

I would imagine that you might be able to find an article from prior to 2004 showing how to create an equivalent user defined function.

Comment: Actually we are using V5R2 and it seems the function could not be found in OS libraries